How to simplify the following stability criteria?
I'm trying to understand the mathematics explained in the following video. Basically, we want to identify the constraints on the parameters $k_1$ $k_2$ and $T$ to have a stable second-order system using semi-implicit Euler integration. The value of these parameters doesn't need to be physically correct, as we're using them in a video game. In this scenario, T is the delta time between each frame rendered in the game, so it can vary. We want to determine the condition at which the value of T make the system unstable.
I know that they are other integration methods that are more stable (e.g. fully-implicit Euler) than semi-implicit Euler but I just want to understand the math, I'm not looking to find antoher solution.
We have the following second order system:
$$ y +k_1y' + k_2y'' = x + k_3x' $$
Using the semi-implicit Euler method we end up with the following equation:
$$ \pmatrix{y \\ y'}^{(n+1)} = \pmatrix{1 & T \\ \frac{-T}{k_2} & \frac{k_2 - T^2-Tk_1}{k_2}}\pmatrix{y \\ y'}^{(n)} + \pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ \frac{T}{k_2} & \frac{Tk_3}{k_2}}\pmatrix{x \\ x'}^{(n+1)} $$

$n$ is a discrete timestep
$T$ is the deltaTime between each step, $T>0$
$k_1 >0$
$k_2 > 0$

The characteristic polynomial of the first square matrix is:
$$k_2*z^2 + (T^2 +Tk_1 - 2k_2)z + (k_2 - Tk_1) = 0$$
The stability criteria the author is using is the following:
$$|\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}| < 1$$
I found and confirmed with SageMath the following roots:
$$ \frac{T^2 + Tk_1 - 2k_2 \pm T\sqrt{T^2 + 2Tk_1 + k1^2 - 4k_2}}{-2k_2} $$
In the video, the author simplifies the inequality to:
$$T < \sqrt{4k_2 + k_1^2} - k1 $$
I have two questions:

How did he get to this simple inequality from the complex equation above? Did he make some assumptions?
I've read that the stability criteria is rather:
$$h \leq \frac{2}{|\lambda|}$$
where $\lambda$ is the root of the equation, as answered here by spektr. Am I missing something?


Please add more details from the video. Where does that characteristic equation come from, a multi-step method, some matrix, ...? Where do $k_1,k_2$ belong to, the ODE or the FD method?

I’ve added more context. Let me know if you need anything else, as my question is more about the simplification of the inequality and the stability criteria I skipped some steps to keep the focus on it.

Maybe the final inequality of the author is a sufficient but not required condition to ensure the stability. So simplifications could have been made to get to this simple result.
